# ¿Cómo puedo descartar los ceros en una consulta sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

comunidad.

estoy intentando descartar los ceros en mi consulta, es decir, le estoy diciendo al query que me traiga el stock de dichos productos,ya lo hace, pero me trae productos que tienen 0 cantidad y yo solo quiero los que tengan a partir de 1

```
SELECT 
[Item No_]+ ' ' + [Barcode No_] AS sku
[Item No_] as producto,
[Barcode No_] as sku,
[Description] as descripcion,
sum([Quantity]) as Cantidad
from [Barcodes]
WHERE YEAR ([Posting Date]) BETWEEN '2015' and '2022' 
    and [Location Code]='SUR' 
    and [Item No_]='A004569'and [Quantity] is not null
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `where tucolumna > 0`

Comment: @lsanchezo, pero como desde la consulta estoy sumando la columna quantity cuando pondo >0 me trae otras cantidades que no son

Comment: recién veo la consulta, sería con having o subquery

Comment: @lsanchezo, listo amigo ya quedo use esto:
HAVING Sum([Quantity]) >0
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 2 opciones, usar WHERE o usar HAVING. Si usas WHERE para eliminar filas en cero, necesitas asegurarte de que no tengas valores negativos que puedan generar una sumatoria de cero.

```
SELECT 
       [Item No_]+ ' ' + [Barcode No_] AS sku
       [Item No_] as producto,
       [Barcode No_] as sku,
       [Description] as descripcion,
       sum([Quantity]) as Cantidad
from [Barcodes]
WHERE YEAR ([Posting Date]) BETWEEN '2015' and '2022' 
    and [Location Code]='SUR' 
    and [Item No_]='A004569'
    and [Quantity] <> 0 -- Esto también eliminará los ceros
GROUP BY [Item No_], --Esta parte le hace falta a tu consulta
         [Barcode No_],
         [Description];
```

En caso de tener negativos, lo ideal es usar HAVING para poder filtrar valores agregados

```
SELECT 
       [Item No_]+ ' ' + [Barcode No_] AS sku
       [Item No_] as producto,
       [Barcode No_] as sku,
       [Description] as descripcion,
       sum([Quantity]) as Cantidad
from [Barcodes]
WHERE YEAR ([Posting Date]) BETWEEN '2015' and '2022' 
    and [Location Code]='SUR' 
    and [Item No_]='A004569'
    and [Quantity] <> 0 -- Esto también eliminará los ceros
GROUP BY [Item No_], --Esta parte le hace falta a tu consulta
         [Barcode No_],
         [Description]
HAVING sum([Quantity]) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

también podría ser con having y group by, acá con subquery:

```sql
select x.*
from ( 
SELECT 
[Item No_]+ ' ' + [Barcode No_] AS sku
[Item No_] as producto,
[Barcode No_] as sku,
[Description] as descripcion,
sum([Quantity]) as Cantidad
from [Barcodes]
WHERE YEAR ([Posting Date]) BETWEEN '2015' and '2022' and [Location Code]='SUR' and [Item No_]='A004569'and [Quantity] is not null
) x
where Cantidad > 0
```